# unserialize() выводит перенос строки в начале документа - это норма?

Tags: php, xml, kohana, десериализация

Пишу шлюз для оплаты, нужно вывалить платежному серверу xml-ответ. Столкнулся с тем, что стандартная авторизация фреймворка Kohana 3 выводит перенос строки непонятного происхождения в начале документа.

Копнул глубже, оказалось что перенос строки происходит при десериализации сессии.
Например вот это

```
echo 123;
$object = unserialize($data);
```

выведет

```
123
Тело документа
```

тогда как вот это

```
$object = unserialize($data);
echo 123;
```

Выведет

```
(пустая строка)
123Тело документа
```

Разумеется, пустая строка убивает мой xml. И после проверки оказалось, что она всегда была со мной, просто раньше не мешала. 
Почему так происходит? Что с этим можно сделать?

---

Временно решил проблему очисткой буфера вывода, перед выводом тела сгенерированного документа, но это немного попахивает, как по мне.

Answer (score 1):

Если что, проблема была вот в чем:
unserialize() получал строковое представление объекта, описание класса которого находилось в файле с переносом строки перед `<?php` 
При попытке воссоздать объект с этим классом, интерпретатор класс не нашел и, потому как автозагрузчик классов Коханы работает исправно, заинклудил файл с этим переносом строки. Отак.
А вот мой фэйл:

[image: мой фэйл]